# Is there a place on the AWS SES console to see when you updated a email template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Next to the template they list the date created, is there a place I can see when it was last updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment, no such functionality is provided. If you call the `list-templates` operation in AWS CLI, you can see that only `CreatedTimestamp` stored in the Template Metadata. Currently, the last update date is not stored at the metadata level.

```
aws ses list-templates

{
    "TemplatesMetadata": [
        {
            "CreatedTimestamp": "2020-01-17T11:44:05.147Z", 
            "Name": "Template-Name"
        }
    ]
}
```